# How to get a value from a checkbox element with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring

Firstly, I concede that I'm a neophyte Spring user! What I'm attempting is to determine what type of user is registering for my application: a 3 month user or 6 month user! I am using a checkbox that is not selected by default in my user registration template (view). So, if it is not checked, the user will, by default, be a 3 month user, and obviously the converse of that otherwise. I am not exactly sure how to approach getting this data (3 month user /6 month user) and sending the correct role to my database (model). I solicit any and all help or direction:

```
   <input id="userrole" type="checkbox" name="role" value="6 month user" th:checked="${flag}" />
                <span>User Role</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the 
    
tag to create the checkbox. Where userrole is the domain attribute which is a boolean variable, set to false at declaration.

Comment: the form tag (<form:checkbox path='userrole'/>)